# Django Combining AND and OR Queries with ManyToMany Field

Tags: mysql, django, many-to-many, django-queryset

hoping someone can help me out with this.

I'm trying to figure out whether I can construct a query that will allow me to retrieve items from my db based on a ForeignKey field and a ManyToManyField at the same time. The challenging part is that it will need to filter on multiple ManyToMany objects.

An example will hopefully make this clearer. Here are my (simplified) models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='brand')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I would like to build a query that retrieves items based on two criteria:

1. Items that were uploaded by users that a user is following (called 'brand' in the model). So for example if a user is following the Paramount user account, I would want all items where brand = Paramount.
2. Items that match the keywords in saved searches. For example the user could make and save the following search: "80s comedy". In this case I would want all items where the tags include both "80s" and "comedy".

Now I know how to construct the query for each independently. For #1, it's:

```
items = Item.objects.filter(brand=brand)
```

And for #2 (based on the docs):

```
items = Item.objects.filter(tags__name='80s').filter(tags__name='comedy')
```

My question is: is it possible to construct this as a single query so that I don't have to take the hit of converting each query into a list, joining them, and removing duplicates?

The challenge seems to be that there is no way to use Q objects to construct queries where you need an item's manytomany field (in this case tags) to match multiple values. The following query:

```
items = Item.objects.filter(Q(tags__name='80s') & Q(tags__name='comedy'))
```

does NOT work.

(See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships)

Thanks in advance for your help on this!

Comment: Do you want the two criteria to be 'joined with an AND'?

Comment: Hi Arustgi, I actually need each criteria to be joined with an OR. So continuing the example above I would be looking for all items that have (brand='brand') OR (tag__name='80s' and tag__name='comedy')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much research I could not find a way to combine this into a single query, so I ended up converting my QuerySets into lists and combining them.

Answer (score 2):

Django's filters automatically AND. `Q` objects are only needed if you're trying to add ORs. Also, the `__in` query filter will help you out alot.

Assuming users have multiple brands they like and you want to return any brand they like, you should use:

```
`brand__in=brands`
```

Where `brands` is the queryset returned by something like `someuser.brands.all()`.

The same can be used for your search parameters:

```
`tags__name__in=['80s','comedy']`
```

That will return things tagged with either '80s' or 'comedy'. If you need both (things tagged with both '80s' AND 'comedy'), you'll have to pass each one in a successive filter:

```
keywords = ['80s','comedy']
for keyword in keywords:
    qs = qs.filter(tags__name=keyword)
```

**P.S.** `related_name` values should always specify the opposite relationship. You're going to have logic problems with the way you're doing it currently. For example:

```
brand = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='brand')
```

Means that `somebrand.brand.all()` will actually return `Item` objects. It should be:

```
brand = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='items')
```

Then, you can get a brands's items with `somebrand.items.all()`. Makes much more sense.

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for the response. I actually am using brand__in=brands in my actual code (was just simplifying above), and since I need things tagged with both tags am also constructing the tags query exactly as you described here. What I'm stuck on is whether there's a way to do both in a single query? Something along the lines logically of items = (brands__in=brands) OR (for keyword in keywords:...)? Or do I have to convert each to a list and combine? Also thank for the great suggestion regarding related_name values - have already made the change. Thanks again!

Comment: You can filter a queryset as many times as you like; there's still only one query to the DB. Django querysets are lazy: they don't actually evaluate until you do something with them that requires evaluation, such as iterating over their items.